# Sideloaded appinstaller not referencing appinstaller on server when checking for updates

Tags: windows-10, msix, appinstaller

I'm trying to deploy an application via the appinstaller for Windows. The appinstaller xml references the appinstaller file on the server which is overwritten when deploying new versions. My understanding is that this behaviour is intended so that when the appinstaller service checks for application updates, it references the endpoint to the appinstaller on the server (the one overwritten by new versions). Currently the appinstaller only seems to reference the msix on the server that it was initially installed with.

This is resulting in the appinstaller redownloading the msix of the current version rather than the new one and I'm unsure if it's doing anything with it.

The application itself is a dummy client with a service which runs under localSystem. Initially I thought that the permissions required to then stop the service would block the appinstaller from installing it, however I don't see any access denied errors in the event log pertaining to this issue.

Notably this event log under Microsoft-Windows-AppxDeploymentServer/Operational references the app ID and coincides with when the appinstaller hits the server:

Started deployment UpdateUsingAppInstallerOperation operation on a package with main parameter 49d89e30-8b49-4435-844d-14ed2c10de79_0.1.2.0_x86__stehcx39bde72 and Options 0 and 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

I've tried tweaking the details of the deployment but I've not found any particular permutation of settings that result in the updating I need. I was able to determine that the appinstaller was referencing the package rather than the new appinstaller via wireshark. The endpoints are all http, https doesn't appear to work. The appinstaller itself is installed via the PowerShell command `Add-AppxPackage -AppInstallerFile`.